# React Native Expo And Third Party Packages

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have been developing appplications using React Native , Expo . Recently,I tried to include a third party library (React Native Tab View https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view) but I can't seem to get the third party components to be rendered to the screen . I have tried     react-native link    but it still doesn't seem to work . Does Expo support all react native 3rd party packages?

Comment: Please post what have you got so far and try to state your question more precisely.

Comment: Does Expo support all react native 3rd party packages?

Answer (score 0):

Those 3rd party packages that have native code and use `react-native link <package>` are not supported by Expo, only pure JS packages.